# Why my ubuntu server is showing less storage space?

Tags: server, partitioning

I have just just turn my old laptop in local server and I am using Ubuntu Server OS (Version:Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS).My laptop have 500gb hdd but my ubuntu serevr is showing just 97.8 gb total space. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvYLn.png)

And laptop have only one big partition of 462gb.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaqLY.png)

How can i solve my problem?Its ok if my data removed by method to fix this problem:)
.[image][image][image]

Comment: What OS version are you using?  14.04 is EOL

Comment: @guiverc I misEdit i am using Ubuntu Server operating system version ( Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS )

Comment: @guiverc I have edited my question....

Comment: @guiverc can you help me regarding my issue?

Comment: Your largest drive - sda - is split into 3 partitions sda1, 2, and 3. Inside of sda3 you have a lvm partition (?) which is only 100 G, and that is where your operating system is installed. Take a closer look at the image you posted. And, in future, don't post images of text. Copy and paste the text into your question. I don't know how to fix this, because I don't use lvm and know nothing about it.

Comment: can you explain me in one line or two line so that i can search it?